# pass an ARRAY<STRUCT> to a js UDF in bigquery sql

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to get data from some tables, and pass them to a JavaScript UDF in bigquery.

I wrote the following code but I can't seem to understand the correct syntax to to store the result of my select in the wanted structure, then how to pass it to my udf function.

```
DECLARE arg1 ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE arg2 ARRAY<STRUCT <col1 STRING, col2 STRING> >;
DECLARE res1 ARRAY<STRING>;

SET arg1 = ARRAY<STRING>["Adams", "Joseph", "Davis", "Mary", "Jesus"] ;


CREATE TEMP FUNCTION  myfunction(arg1 ARRAY<STRING> , arg2 ARRAY<STRUCT<col1 STRING, col2 STRING> > ) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
return ["a", "b", "c"]
''';

SET ARG2 = (SELECT AS STRUCT(
WITH TBL1 AS
 (SELECT 'Adams' as LastName, 50 as SchoolID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Buchanan', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Coolidge', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Davis', 51 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Eisenhower', 77)
SELECT LastName as col1, SchoolID as col2 FROM TBL1));

SET res1 = select res FROM UNNEST(myfunction( arg1, arg2 )) res;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors with the code you shared but based on the procedural logic, I've made a few adjustments to a more declarative style and corrected these.

1. I have kept `arg1` even though we may also include this in the `TBL1` CTE if desired
2. `arg2` is now created by selected the values from `TBL1` as a `STRUCT` and the columns are renamed using `as col1` and `as col2`
3. I've casted `SchoolId` as a `string` since your UDF accepts `col2` as string
4. I've added another field `id` for demo purposes as I will group or aggregate the data by this `id` column to get the array of struct `arg2` parameter required by your UDF
5. I finally select `id` and call your `UDF` with the parameters in the correct format. `array_agg` is used to create the array of structs here. The result is in a column named `res2`

```sql
DECLARE arg1 ARRAY<STRING>;

SET arg1 = ARRAY<STRING>["Adams", "Joseph", "Davis", "Mary", "Jesus"] ;


CREATE TEMP FUNCTION  myfunction(arg1 ARRAY<STRING> , arg2 ARRAY<STRUCT<col1 STRING, col2 STRING> > ) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
return ["a", "b", "c"]
''';

WITH TBL1 AS (
  SELECT 'Adams' as LastName, 50 as SchoolID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Buchanan', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Coolidge', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Davis', 51 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Eisenhower', 77
),
tbl2 as (
    SELECT 
        1 as id, 
        STRUCT( 
            LastName as col1, 
            CAST(SchoolID as STRING) as col2
        ) as arg2 
    FROM TBL1
)
select id, myfunction(arg1, array_agg( arg2)) as res1 from tbl2
group by id
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the fixes and the explanations ggordon! And for those who care, it's possible to access the STRUCT in the js code this way: arg2[0]["col1"]